# what is meaning of error(1,-17)?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, error-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android:mediaplayer error(1, -17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092115/androidmediaplayer-error1-17)

```
error(1,-17)
```

I am using mediaplayer in my app and sometimes I got error(1,-17) in my logcat 
anyone has any idea what it means ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error probably comes from MediaPlayer. You could them [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h). Your error should be

> Error due to general error in underlying resource

and I don't clearly sure what this mean.

Answer (score 0):

The error code `-17` stands for an error in your resource file. Most likely, your source audio/video/media file is using a codec, or some format that the Android MediaPlayer does not support.

Try converting your file to a format supported by Android.

This can also be caused by having too many MediaPlayer objects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this answer

Please make sure you don't have too many MediaPlayer objects active at once. See [this](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/138/topics/3561) for reference.

[android:mediaplayer error(1, -17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092115/androidmediaplayer-error1-17)