# Mediaplayer Error(1, -17)

Tags: android, media-player

guys i have the following code

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer rp = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer rpp = new MediaPlayer();
case R.id.bok:


i = 0;
                time = Integer.valueOf(noOfTimes.getText().toString());
            System.out.println("got the value" + time);

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.startup_converted);
            mp.start();
            if (skipintro.isChecked()) {

                //String path = "/sdcard/varun/audio.mp3";  

                    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            try {
                                rp.reset();
                                rp.setDataSource("/sdcard/varun/audio.mp3");
                                rp.prepare();
                                rp.start();
                                System.out.println("played once");

                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(r1,mp.getDuration()+1000);

                    //sdcard.start();

                rp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("no of times is "+time);
                        System.out.println("i value is  "+i);

                        if(i < time-1){
                            System.out.println("inside no of times is "+time);
                            System.out.println("inside i value is  "+i);

                        try {
                            rp.reset();
                            rp.setDataSource("/sdcard/varun/audio.mp3");
                            rp.prepare();
                            rp.start();
                            System.out.println("playing=== a");

                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                });

                ok.setEnabled(false);

                rpp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.conclution);
                hand1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        rpp.start();
                    }
                }, mp.getDuration()+ time * rp.getDuration());
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ok.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                },mp.getDuration()+time* rp.getDuration()+rpp.getDuration());
```

i ma getting the error(1, -4)

```
03-02 16:45:19.249: W/System.err(14450): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
03-02 16:45:19.267: W/System.err(14450):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
03-02 16:45:19.295: W/System.err(14450):    at samcomm.myhealth.management.Relaxation$3.run(Relaxation.java:242)
03-02 16:45:19.315: W/System.err(14450):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-02 16:45:19.326: W/System.err(14450):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-02 16:45:19.335: W/System.err(14450):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-02 16:45:19.335: W/System.err(14450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-02 16:45:19.345: W/System.err(14450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 16:45:19.365: W/System.err(14450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-02 16:45:19.377: W/System.err(14450):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-02 16:45:19.377: W/System.err(14450):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-02 16:45:19.385: W/System.err(14450):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me

Comment: aren't you supposed to give it an uri, like file:///sdcard/something?

Comment: i think its not the problem of path it the problem with mediaplayer it plays 3 times but 4th time it shows this error

Comment: I see you use multiple mediaplayers. This could cause the problem. Try to limit the number of mediaplayers that are running at the same time.

Comment: See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8470932/741249)

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the .mp3 file in sd card .How to store : go to a file Explorer choose sd card ,Select (push a file on to the device) this name button,Select any one mp3 file click open button after that run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

rp.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/varun/audio.mp3");